# Is there a way to specify different bundle display names for different iOS devices in a universal app?

Tags: iphone

I'm guessing no, but would love to be wrong. I would like to use a bundle display name for my universal app that shows great on the iPad and iPhone 4, but is too long (has ellipses) on older iPhone models. I'd like to specify the full bundle display name on the former two platforms, and then specify a shorter name on older iPhone models. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 4.1 there isn't any way to do this. You can specify different bundle display names for iPad vs. iPhone, but there's no way to specify different bundle display names for the old iPhone vs. iPhone 4.

Comment: How do you specify them?

Answer (score 5):

My first guess would be `InfoPlist~ipad.strings`.

Comment: Oh neat, I didn't know about that. Apparently I should be able to set a CFBundleDisplayName~ipad key in the Info.plist as well. I can't find a way to differentiate iPhone 4 though.

Comment: Unlikely to work, but InfoPlist@2x.strings or CFBundleDisplayName@2x?

Comment: This is really awesome - confirmed as working by me, running Xcode 4.0.2 and targeting 4.0+ on my universal app. So if you set a CFBundleDisplayName and a CFBundleDisplayName~ipad key in the Info.plist file, you can have both.